# when using php web service to develop and android application how to authenticate instead of php session?

Tags: php, android, web-services, android-volley

In a php web application we can check if user is logged in or not by using sessions , my android app will use volley to call php api which will send a json response from remote web server , if user get their profile or update something it will call `userdetail.php` , how server will know it is a authenticated request or not ? or else I need to send username and password along with all api calls , Is this a correct way ? or is there any other ways available to do the same ?

Comment: For mobile application, the common method is to generate a unique token for each user when he/she login on the mobile app. Every time the app makes a request to the API, send along the token for the purpose of authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The way I had implemented this is when login hit a **API** and update a token field in the user table and send it back with response and user details.

Every time the user hit an API , check the token along with the email or username whichever is unique and send back the result.

Note - the token column only changes after the login not after that.

Comment: after login, token will be added in user table, and if next time api goes to server with a token  right? token will be generated in server ? If they logout from device what happen ? and login again ?

Comment: yes a random token will be generated, and on logout just update the token field as blank and again if the user login same process will follow as generate a new token and send it with user details

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel tymon/jwt-auth library to generate jwt tokens to authenticate users instead of PHP sessions which maintain state.